# Does $X_{2n}=\langle x,y|x^n=y^2=1,xy=yx^2\rangle$ really have order $6$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation

Here is the entire question:

> Let $X_{2n}=\langle x,y\mid x^n=y^2=1,xy=yx^2\rangle $  and $n=3k$ then show that $X_{2n}$ has order $6$.

Here is my question:

> How do we know that $X_{2n}$ has order $6$ and not order $2$?

---

While tackling this question I assumed that the statement

> $x^n=1$

would mean that

> $x^k\neq 1$ for $1\leq k\leq n-1$

But as you go through this problem you can prove that $x^3=1$.

Well this lead to a deeper question about the uniqueness presentations.

> Sure we could have the group $G=\{1,x,x^2,y,yx,yx^2\}$ satisfy the relation, but why doesn't $G=\{1,y\}$ not also satify the relation?

Comment: Adding the relation $x=e$ changes the group.  The trivial group also satisfies the relations.

Comment: @lulu So presentations aren't unique?

Comment: Not following.  Are you asking if one group can have more than one presentation?  If so, the answer is "of course".  The Word Problem famously tells you that there is no algorithm for deciding if a given presentation leads to the trivial group, for example.

Comment: @lulu I am asking if a presentation can be satisfied by nonisomorpic groups.

Comment: Then the answer is "of course not".  In your case you added a new relation (namely $x=e$) so the presentations are not the same.

Comment: Perhaps something that might clarify your confusion: a group satisfying all the relations in a presentation does NOT imply that it is the group defined by that presentation. (It only implies that it is a quotient of that group.) The group defined by a presentation is the "largest" group satisfying the presentation. In the finite case, a common way to proceed is to prove that the group given by the presentation must have at most a certain order, and then find a group of that order satisfying the relations. This proves that this is a presentation for that group.

Comment: Also, in a presentation, $x^n=1$, does NOT necessarily imply that $x^i\neq 1$ for smaller $i$'s.

Comment: For example, the group $\langle x\mid \rangle$ (with one generator and no relation) is the infinite cyclic group. (Isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z},+)$.) Note that every cyclic group also ``satisfies'' this presentation, because they are all quotients of the infinite one but still, the presentation is only the presentation for the infinite one.

Comment: @user160110 Your assumption on $x^n=1$ that all smaller powers are not 1 is not true. The relation is satisfied by $x$. However the group satisfying all the relations of the presentations is unique up to isomorphism.

Comment: Using the relations $yxy=x^2$ and its consequence $x=y^2xy^2=yx^2y=yx^2y^{-1}=(yxy^{-1})^2=x^4$ we see that $x^3=1$.